# STRING_SPLIT and ordered results

Tags: sql-server

Can you assume that the result of the string_split function returns elements in order? In short, is the following code correct?

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'clothing,road,touring,bike' 
DECLARE @FIRST nvarchar(100);

SELECT TOP 1 @FIRST = value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',');
```

Comment: The function returns a table which is by definition unordered. If you can't find support for a defined order in the documentation, I would not assume that it is.

Comment: For the specific example you can quite easily use `LEFT(@tags,CHARINDEX(',', @tags + ',') - 1)`

Comment: **Azure** SQL's `STRING SPLIT` now supports an `enable_ordinal` parameter, according to [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7039/stringsplit-function-azure-sql-database-ordinal-position/), but I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 17):

`TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` could not be guaranteed to return the same results even if the output of `STRING_SPLIT()` were guaranteed (which it [most definitely is not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)). While in real-world usage you may find it hard to come up with a counter-example where the data is *not* returned in order, this is a terrible kind of thing to do. Trusting that something always works because you've never seen it break is like assuming that if you put a deer sign on the highway that is the only place you'll ever see a deer.

However, let's look at another way we could solve this. Why don't we locate the position of each individual string in the overall list:

```
DECLARE 
  @tags nvarchar(400) = N'clothing,road,touring,bike',
  @c nchar(1) = N',';

SELECT value, CHARINDEX(@c + value + @c, @c + @tags + @c) 
  -- we surround the value and the string with leading/trailing ,
  -- so that cloth isn't a false positive for clothing
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',') AS t;
```

Output here is:

> [image: output with charindex]

Do you think we could use this to determine the first element in the list? Of course! Let's try again:

```
DECLARE 
  @tags nvarchar(400) = N'clothing,road,touring,bike',
  @first nvarchar(100),
  @c nchar(1) = N',';

;WITH t AS
(
  SELECT value, idx = CHARINDEX(@c + value + @c, @c + @tags + @c) 
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')
)
SELECT TOP (1) @first = value FROM t ORDER BY idx;

PRINT @first;
```

Output:

```
clothing
```

You could use the same logic to find the last element, just change the `ORDER BY idx` to `ORDER BY idx DESC`. In fact, you could use this logic to return the **nth** string in the list:

```
DECLARE 
  @tags nvarchar(400) = N'clothing,road,touring,bike',
  @c nchar(1) = N',',
  @nth tinyint;

SET @nth = 3;

;WITH t AS
(
  SELECT value, idx = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(@c + value + @c, @c + @tags + @c))
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')
)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE idx = @nth;
```

Result:

```
touring
```

As a disclaimer, if you have duplicates, that's going to mess things up, because the index value will always represent the **first** appearance of that value in the string. You can switch from `ROW_NUMBER()` to `DENSE_RANK()` but that won't solve for all cases. You can de-dupe the string first ([I talk about some edge cases here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5275/solve-old-problems-with-sql-servers-new-stringagg-and-stringsplit-functions/)).

Comment: `«that's going to mess things up»` @AaronBertrand, There is a simple solution for duplicates which allows you to use STRING_SPLIT and guarantee the order, but it is highly not recommended for production -> only for the sake of the discussion [please check this post](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/223/T-SQL-Playing-with-STRING_SPLIT-function.aspx) with full explanation and "solution"

Comment: @RonenAriely Yeah, I saw. While that is an interesting solution from an academic standpoint, you are quite right that it is not suitable for production (and I don't know how realistic it is to have a comma-separated list that is assembled with duplicates). Everything you've gained from the performance and elegance of STRING_SPLIT() you're just throwing away. At that point I'd rather just use the same type of inline table-valued function that I'd have used before 2016.

Comment: If you don't have duplicates like scenario 1, which I show, and in fact even scenario 2 where there can be only twice or less, then this approach can bring very good performance in some cases. It is when we have multiple duplicates like scenario 3, that "`Everything you've gained from the performance and elegance of STRING_SPLIT() you're just throwing away`", since we start to make use of loop (recursive)

Answer (score 3):

You definitely make a cheating like below:

```
SELECT  value,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY current_timestamp) AS row
FROM    String_Split('your,string,here',',') d
```

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Note, code-only answers are typically not very well received, it is better if you also explain, what are you doing and why.

Comment: How can you know that this forces `string_split` to guarantee the original order?

Comment: @TimLehner: As MS official page, it said "The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string". Therefore it just a trick and will work for 99% cases I believe (you even can ORDER BY NULL). The func is getting improved in the future, you might to follow the post here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902852-string-split-is-not-feature-complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use an identity and a temporary table, something like this..

I think it's cleaner:

```
select  'OrderNum' = identity(int,1,1), * 
into    #tmo
from    STRING_SPLIT ('kjds|kdkjsdhkjshdkj3hjk|3hg43ui46g33754g6325', '|')

select * from #tmo
```

So, you can obtain this result

```
|OrderNum    |value
|----------- |----------------------
|1           |kjds
|2           |kdkjsdhkjshdkj3hjk
|3           |3hg43ui46g33754g6325
```

**BUT, microsoft says, the output order of String_SPLIT function is not guaranteed**

you can obtain the real order with the "ordinal" parameter, but only works for SQL 2022 and forward

Answer (score -1):

this is my variant with guaranteed right sorting:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(256) = N'   a    b x  b  c';
-- creating table with unique identity, for sorting later:
DECLARE @dict TABLE (
    id          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    value       NVARCHAR(256)
);
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(256)  = '';
-- split string on parts and insert rows on @dict:
INSERT @dict SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, ' ') WHERE value <> '';
-- got sorted result:
SELECT value FROM @dict ORDER BY id;
```

Done.

p.s. if you`re wondering, this my function for getting sorted words (like single line):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getWordsFromString] (@string NVARCHAR(256), @offset TINYINT, @limit TINYINT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(256)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- creating table with unique identity, which will be used for sorting below
    DECLARE @dict TABLE (
        id          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        value       NVARCHAR(256)
    );
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(256)  = '';
    IF @offset IS null
        SET @offset = 0;
    IF @limit = 0 OR @limit IS null
        SET @limit = 1;
    -- split string into raws and insert them into temp table
    INSERT @dict SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string, ' ') WHERE value <> '';
    -- aggregate rows into one row splitted by spaces
    SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result + ' ', '') + value
    FROM @dict
    ORDER BY id-- сортируем по позиции слова в строке
    OFFSET @offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY;
    RETURN LTRIM(@result);
END
```

Example usage:

```
SELECT dbo.getWordsFromString(N'   a    b x  b  c', 1, 2);
```

Result:

```
b x
```

Comment: How can you know that this forces `string_split` to guarantee the original order?